# Graph isomorphism when all vertices have the same degree

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Are 2 connected graphs isomorphic if they have the same number of vertices and each vertex has the same degree $k$? I don't know how to prove it but I also can't find a counter example.

Comment: Do your graphs allow edges from a vertex to itself?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi No

Comment: A graph whose vertices all have degree $k$ is usually called $k$-regular.  The [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) is cubic (3-regular) on ten vertices, and has girth (smallest cycle length) 5, so it is not isomorphic to the [prism graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrismGraph.html) one gets by connecting two pentagons (which has girth 4).  3-regular is minimal for nonisomorphic connected regular graphs of equal sizes, but this counterexample does not have [the minimum number of nodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

One of them has a three cycle. They are both cubic graphs.

Comment: Good illustration, I was just going to say "$K_{3,3}$ and a triangular prism". :-)

Comment: I just realized they where $K_{3,3}$ and a triangular prism.

Comment: This counterexample uses the least number of nodes, 6.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k=2$. Graph 1: two triangles. Graph 2: a hexagon.

(OP inserted connected after this answer was posted. The answer is still no.)

Comment: Can you find an example with connected graphs?

Comment: These graphs are the complements of $K_{3,3}$ and the triangular prism.

Answer (score 1):

Start with the cube graph. Add a diagonal to the top face; this increases the degree of two vertices to become $4$. From these vertices, remove the downward edges; this decreases the degree of two bottom vertices. Join these by a face diagonal. This new graph has eight vertices of degree $3$ (like the cube), but has several $3$-cycles (unlike the cube).

Comment: Could you promote your comment to an answer here? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858078/the-only-fixed-point-free-automorphism-of-order-2-is-phia-a-1in-a-fin