# Verification of a problem involving groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $(G, \cdot)$ be a finite group and $f : G \rightarrow G$ be an automorphism such that:
$$f(x) \neq x, \, \forall \, x \in G - \{e\}$$
$$f \, \circ \, f = 1_G$$

Prove that $G$ is abelian.

Here is how I did it:

Since $f \, \circ \, f = 1_G$, $f$ is its own inverse, that is $f^{-1} = f$.

We have $f^{-1}(x) = f(x), \, \forall x \in G$. But $f$ is an automorphism, and that means that $f(x^{-1}) = f^{-1}(x)$. We get $f(x^{-1}) = f(x)$. But $f$ is bijective, so $x = x^{-1}$, or $x^2 = e$ and $G$ is abelian.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858078/the-only-fixed-point-free-automorphism-of-order-2-is-phia-a-1in-a-fin

Comment: The solution provided there is different from my solution. I want to know if my approach is correct.

Comment: The equality $f^{-1}(x)=f(x^{-1})$ does not hold for an arbitrary automorphism. The correct one is that $(f(x))^{-1}=f(x^{-1})$. Thus your solution is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to claim that for an automorphism $f$, it holds that
$$f(x^{-1}) = f^{-1}(x),$$
but this is not necessarily true. An (auto)morphism does have the property that
$$f(x^{-1}) = f(x)^{-1},$$
where the power $-1$ signifies the inverse of the element $f(x)$, and not the inverse of the automorphism $f$.

**Example**: consider the group $\mathbb{Z},+$ with the identity automorphism $\textrm{id}$. Clearly $\textrm{id}(x^{-1}) = x^{-1}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, however, the inverse $\textrm{id}$ is $\textrm{id}$, so $\textrm{id}^{-1}(x) = \textrm{id}(x) = x$. Thus
$$\textrm{id}(x^{-1}) = x^{-1} \neq x = \textrm{id}^{-1}(x)$$
for any $x \neq e$.

Answer (score 2):

we have that $f$ is an automorphism then $f(x^2)=f(x.x)=f(x).f(x)=f(x).f^{-1}(x)=e$ then $x^2=e$ therefore G is abelian.