# the number of the subgroups of a finite group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=P \ltimes Q$, where $P \cong Q_8$ and $Q \cong \Bbb{Z}_q \times \Bbb{Z}_q$ is an elementary abelian $q$-group for some prime $q \neq 2$. Let $Q$ is irreducible as $P$_module and the action of $P$ on $Q$ is faithful. 
Then why $G$ has exactly $q(q+1)$ dihedral subgroups of order $2q$?

My Try: There exists a homomorphism $\varphi: P \longrightarrow
 {\rm Aut}(Q)$ such that $Ker(\varphi)=1$. We know $P$ has exactly involution, say $x$. Since $Ker(\varphi)=1$, we have ${\varphi}_x :=\varphi(x) \neq id_Q$ and ${\varphi}_x : Q \longrightarrow Q$ via:

$\forall y \in Q, \ y \longmapsto y^x:=x^{-1} yx \neq x$.
Also we see that $|{\varphi}_x|=2$.

On the other hand i know the fact that  a group generated by two involutions is dihedral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $Q_8$ has a unique element of order $2$, all subgroups of order $2q$ are contained in $H:=\langle Q,x \rangle$.

Note that $C_Q(x)$ is normalized by  $P$. Since the action of $P$ on $Q$ is faithful, we have $C_Q(x) \ne Q$ and hence, since the action is irreducible, $C_Q(x) = 1$. But then (by a well-known result) we must have  $x^{-1}yx = y^{-1}$ for all $y \in Q$.

Now $Q$, and hence also $H$, has $q+1$ subgroups of order $q$, and they are all normal in $H$.

There are exactly $q^2$ elements of order $2$ in $H$ (the conjugates of $x$ under $Q$), and each of them generates a  dihedral group of order $2q$, with any subgroup of $Q$ of order $q$.

Each such dihedral subgroup contains $q$ elements of order $2$, so each of the subgroups of order $q$ lies in $q^2/q = q$ dihedral subgroups of order $2q$.

That makes a total of $q(q+1)$ dihedral subgroups.

Comment: I added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: excuse me, when $C_Q(x)=1$, we have $\lbrace y \in Q \mid y^x=y \rbrace=1$. that is $\forall y \in Q, y^x \neq y$. where i can find this well-known result?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858078/

Comment: Please stop asking more and more questions in comments. You have accepted the answer.