# Example of fixed point free of order 2 which is not inverse mapping

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

I just learn about fixed point free of order 2 and when G is finite, this is nothing but map $\phi (x)= x^{-1}$. I am looking for example of fixed point free of order 2 which is not the map which $\phi (x)= x^{-1}$.

Comment: What do you mean with fixed point free of order 2, and with finite case? Your $\phi$ is of order 2 (aka, involutory), but has fixed points $\pm1$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858078/the-only-fixed-point-free-automorphism-of-order-2-is-phia-a-1in-a-fin

Comment: Oh, so from *Believer*'s comment I infer that a lot of context is missing: The question is about automorphisms, not maps, the domain is a group (abelian), and the trivial fixpoint $1$ is not counted